# jQuery hide or show based on my drop down selected with drop down 4 options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me out!

Here is my Jquery code:

```
function showhide() {
    var merchanttype = jQuery("#merchant_type").val();
    var status = true;
    if (merchanttype == "DM" || "SM") {
        jQuery("#parent_merchant_id").show();
        status = false;
    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery("#parent_merchant_id").hide();
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="label-right">Merchant Type<span class="red">*</span></td>
    <td><select  id="merchant_type" name="merchant_type" class="frm-select" onchange="showhide()">
        <option value="MM">Master Merchant </option>
        <option value="MPM">Market Place Merchant</option>
        <option value="DM">Distributor Merchant</option>
        <option value="SM">Supplier Merchant</option>

        </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="label-right">Parent Id <span class="red">*</span></td>
    <!-- td><input name="parent_merchant_id" type="text"  maxlength="40" value="" class="frm-field" /> <br /> </td-->
    <td>
        <select id="parent_merchant_id" name="parent_merchant_id" class="frm-select">
        </select>
    </td>                     
</tr>
```

i want to hide parent id when merchant type is MM or MPM show the same field for DM And MPM

Comment: what do you mean by show the same field?

Comment: show the parent id for Drop down selection DM OR SM

Comment: It should have been (merchanttype == "DM" || merchanttype == "SM")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that but hope this will work for you

[See It in action](http://jsfiddle.net/hnsKr/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#merchant_type').change(function(){
       var v= $("#merchant_type option:selected")[0].value;
        if(v==='MPM'|| v==='MM'){
          $('#dependant').hide();
        }else{
          $('#dependant').show();
        }
    }); 
});
```

where `<tr id="dependant">`

Comment: you can thank by 'accepting' the answer. its just a click :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and the condition is wrong - you are only checking for `DM` the `SM` value is not checked

```
function showhide() {
    var merchanttype = jQuery("#merchant_type").val();
    jQuery("#parent_merchant_id").toggle(merchanttype == "DM" || merchanttype == "MPM");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
function showhide() {
var merchanttype = jQuery("#merchant_type").val();
var status = true;
if (merchanttype == "DM" || merchanttype == "SM") {
    jQuery("#parent_merchant_id").show();
    status = false;
} else if (status == true) {
    jQuery("#parent_merchant_id").hide();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you stated the problem in a form that can be answered. Can you provide more html and cleanup your question? It would be good to see the id 'merchant_type' anywhere in the html section to understand what element type it is (I suppose it's a checkbox?).
Also state what happens or what errors you see please.

Comment: merchant_type is a drop down box